# Адаптация кода с записи в бинарный файл в запись в буфер в памяти

Tags: c++, fstream, buffer

У меня возникли проблемы с конвертацией кода.

`imagedata` - это исходный буфер где хранится изображение. Полный код который я взял за основу [тут](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/renderheadless/renderheadless.cpp). Я этот буфер формирую через Vulkan API.

Вот есть такой код для записи в файл.

```cpp
        for (int32_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            unsigned int *row = (unsigned int *)imagedata;
            for (int32_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                file.write((char *)row, 4);
                row++;
            }
            imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch;
        }
        file.close();
```

Далее я при помощи библиотеки `stb_image_writter` загружаю созданный файл и формирую изображение. Всё отлично работает.

P.S.: при этом какая-то странная проблема. Я вообще могу записывать и через исходный буфер `imagedata`, но есть проблема на интегрированных GPU. Если ширина фреймбуфера не кратна 2-м, то вместо изображения какая-то ересь. В общем оно поломано. Видимо, как в примере, этот цикл нужен для выравнивания памяти в буфере. И действительно так у меня всё работает.

Создавать файл бинарный мне не нужно и мне хотелось бы записывать это всё в буфер в памяти. Я попробовал сделать так, но почему-то изображение получается чёрно-белым. Видимо я что-то забыл или переписал криво.

```cpp
std::vector<char> data{};
        for (int32_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            unsigned int *row = (unsigned int *)imagedata;
            for (int32_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                data.push_back(row[0]);
                data.push_back(row[1]);
                data.push_back(row[2]);
                data.push_back(row[3]);
                row++;
            }
            imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch;
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так? Ведь если экспортировать в бинарный файл, а потом загружать из него работает. Значит проблемой скорей всего является мой переписанный код.
Насколько я понимаю `file.write` берет данные из `row` и вставляет в файл первые `n` элементов. Я вроде сделал также через `push_back`, но почему тогда не работает?

И кстати, я добавлю, если заменить код в цикле на:

```cpp
data.push_back(row[0]);
data.push_back(row[0]);
data.push_back(row[0]);
data.push_back(row[0]);
```

то вообще ничего не изменится. Будет также чёрно-белое изображение. Может быть я не правильно обращаюсь к переменной `row` ?

Попробовал сделать через `stringstream` - работает. Но мне кажется это не лучший способ. В общем подытожив можно сказать что вопрос заключается в том как переписать код так, чтобы функционально он был таким же как это делается через `stream.write`

UPD: Также моя попытка через `char*`:

```cpp
        char *data = new char[width * height * 4];
        for (int32_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            unsigned int *row = (unsigned int *)imagedata;
            for (int32_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                data[y + x] = (char)*(row);
                data[y + x + 1] = (char)*(row + 1);
                data[y + x + 2] = (char)*(row + 2);
                data[y + x + 3] = (char)*(row + 3);
                row++;
            }
            imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch;
        }
        stbi_write_jpg("testFromBuffer.jpg", width, height, 4, data, 100);
        delete[] data;
```

Comment: В файл вставляется 4 байта за итерацию, а вектор - 16. Все c-style касты - ни к чему.

Comment: @user7860670 Ок, а что делать чтобы решить проблему? Я дополнил ответ. Я также попробовал сделать через `char*`, но тогда просто чёрный экран вместо изображения. Что в этом случае мб не так?

Comment: Для начала избавьтесь от c-style кастов, затем прочитайте, как работают указатели. Новый вариант отличается от второго только в худшую сторону, причем по-прежнему проглатывает 16 байт за итерацию.

Comment: @user7860670  а можете привести пример как надо? Я так понял что из-за того что `row` - `unsigned int` я сразу отпралвяю большее количество байт и поэтому я и получаю чёрно-белое изображение. Как вы и сказали я попробовал убрать все касты, даже убрал саму переменую `row`. Но получвется какая-то белиберда. Видимо я не очень понимаю как пофиксить. Не могли бы вы мне разжевать на примере и указать где у меня ошибка и как нужно сделать правильно?

Comment: Весь внутренний цикл заменяется на `::std::memcpy(static_cast<void *>(data), static_cast<void const *>(imagedata), width * 4);` Выражение `imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch;` возможно тоже неправильное, однако из приведенного кода не ясно, что такое `imagedata`.

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался.
Мне нужно было перед добавлением сделать cast `row` в `char` т.к. как было сказано @user7860670 отправляется 16 байт вместо 4.

```cpp
std::vector<char> data{};
for (int32_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    unsigned int *row = (unsigned int *)imagedata;
    for (int32_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            data.push_back(reinterpret_cast<char*>(row)[i]);
        row++;
    }
    imagedata += subResourceLayout.rowPitch;
}
```

Также нашёл замечательный [пример](https://github.com/RamseyK/ByteBufferCpp) пока гуглил. Там объясняется как это делается через `memcpy`.